# How is "whinge" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

I once noticed somebody spelled "whine" as "whinge" and thought it was an egregious and hilarious typo. But it turns out that "whinge" is an acceptable spelling among writers of the "Queen's" (British) English (I've never seen it written that way by an American).

So: how is "whinge" pronounced - the same way as "whine," with a long "i" (but a silent "g")? If it is pronounced otherwise, is it a long or short "i"? And is it a silent "g", a soft "g" ("j") or a hard "g" (as in "goat")?

Comment: Ask the OED — or a Scot: both will tell you it’s /hwɪndʒ/.

Comment: Perhaps it was [my recent usage in a comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197838/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-wind-your-neck-in/197861#comment418043_197861) that you "once noticed". I must be honest and admit that earlier on I'd specifically written ***whining*** in my answer text, because I wasn't sure whether to spell the word I *really* meant to use with an ***e*** or not. With *singing, singeing* we need the ***e*** to resolve ambiguity, but apparently it's not required in ***whinging***. (Spelling not being my strong point, I checked before daring to use it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No, it was on StackOverflow, several months (at least) ago.

Comment: @B. Clay Shannon: You obviously have a better memory than me! I'd only used the word 10-15 minutes before your post here, and I was still annoyed with myself for being such a lousy speller. But if it had been several *hours* earlier (let alone days, weeks, or months) I'm sure I'd have forgotten. The awful truth for me is I'll probably have to Google the spelling *again* next time I want to write ***whinging***. (That's not counting *this* time, which I checked by looking at my earlier comment here! :)

Comment: I have a selectively crummy (crumby?) memory; I can remember somebody using the word "whinge" a year ago, but I can't remember my license plate number, which I see several times a day, or the names of most of my former pets.

Comment: On a related note, [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/292344/316609) to a different question about "whinge" explains the history of the word, and how it overlaps but is not quite identical in meaning to "whine".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually pronounced winjde (wɪn(d)ʒ)

A [simple google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20whinge) would tell you - it has a listen button.

Comment: That is doubly hilarious; contemplating somebody "WIN-jing" makes what is otherwise a pitiable state quite maudlin and macabre.

Comment: That is not what the OED has.

Comment: @tchrist what does it have?

Comment: It has /hwɪndʒ/.